# Dynamically add Text to same Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to add the text dynamically to the same span. Have generated an index to the id so that based on index thought to add the text.

This is what i have tried.
Expected output is I need to create one more span with same id but different index and append my array values to the span with index values.

Expected Output Example:

```
<span id="test-0">test</span>
<span id="test-1">Demo</span>
```

HTML:

```
<span id="test-{{$index}}"></span>
```

JS:

```
var arr = [{"Name":"test"},{"Name":"Demo"}];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    txt = arr[i].Name;
    $('#test-'+i).text(txt);
}
```

Tried Demo:
[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wngrzmfu/)

Comment: Elaborate your problem please. What is your expected output?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wtokg4sv/ see this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#test-'+i).text(txt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign value in `text()` function

```
$('#test-'+i).text();
```

to

```
$('#test-'+i).text(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can have a `div` to add `span` which will have dynamic id and text from array.

HTML-

```
  <div id="test"></div>
```

javascript: -

```
var arr = [{"Name":"test"},{"Name":"Demo"}];
var $text = $('#test');
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
   $text.append('<span id="test-'+i+'">'+arr[i].Name+'</span>');
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wngrzmfu/1/)**

Comment: Unable to append the data, while appending it should one more span with different index value and then append the other text

Answer (score 0):

You can use string builder, such as:

```
var arr = [{ "Name": "test" }, { "Name": "Demo" }];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    txt = arr[i].Name;
    document.write("<span id=test-" + i + ">" + txt + "</span>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle you had given is wrong. which has been edited as follows.

[check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wtokg4sv/)

```
 var arr = [{"Name":"test"},{"Name":"Demo"}];
   for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
   //append existing text to new value from array
   var txt = $('#test'+i).text() + arr[i].Name;
   $('#test'+i).text(txt);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use angular, you are going about it all wrong.  Angular doesn't play well with html elements added elsewhere, they have to be compiled first so angular can bind to them.  In this instance you could use `ng-repeat` to bind a list to a series of spans:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in [100, 200, 300, 400]" id="test-{{$index}}">
    Index is {{$index}}<br/>
</span>
```

You also need to include angular in your fiddle and have an element with the `ng-app` tag ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/22zqto9u/2/)).  Using angular you would also have a named controller and set a property on the scope to your array, but that is outside the bounds if this question.